# strange parsing Double behaviour

Tags: c#

I have this line of code:

```
return (this.pretWithoutDiscount / Double.Parse(UtilsStatic.getEuroValue())).ToString("N2") + "€";
```

In debug mode i've tested and the values are:

> UtilsStatic.getEuroValue() = "4.1878"
>
> this.pretWithoutDiscount = 111.0

Can anyone explaing WHY:

> Double.Parse(UtilsStatic.getEuroValue()) = 41878.0

when it should be 4.1878 ??

Thanks...

PS: UtilsStatic.getEuroValue returns a string.

Comment: What happens if you use InvariantCulture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What decimal seprator are you using, my guess would be ','. Try

```
Double.Parse(UtilsStatic.getEuroValue(), 
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

which will parse the number using '.' as the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you..It's working NOW with IC...What is strange is that this code has worked very well and although i have developed new modules i do not know how it has been broken......

Comment: @Cristian Probably running on machines with differenct windows cultures. If you specify nothing .net goes with windows locale

Comment: @Cristian There ya go ;) Always use invariantculture if it is not to be displayed for user but parsed or saved in database

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are dealing with money, so `decimal` type should be used instead of `double`.

Comment: -1 Comment, not an answer as this does not answer his question. Although you are correct with the decimal

Comment: -1. How does this answer has anything to do with the question?